# DocuSign Node SDK not returning loginInfo in Production

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I've built out an integration using [DocuSign's Node SDK.](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-node-client) While testing using a DocuSign sandbox account, the authentication flow works just fine using the example in the docs.

I'm now trying to do the same within a live DocuSign production account using the Integrator Key that was promoted from the sandbox account. `authApi.login()` seems to work just fine, I get no error and the status code of the response is 200. However, the value of `loginInfo` comes back as `exports {}` with no account info included.

I've made sure to change the base path from `https://demo.docusign.net/restapi` to `www.docusign.net/restapi` and as far as I can tell from the docs, there doesn't seem to be anything else I need to make the switch to production. Here is the code I am using:

```
apiClient.setBasePath('www.docusign.net/restapi');
apiClient.addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);

docusign.Configuration.default.setDefaultApiClient(apiClient);
const authApi = new docusign.AuthenticationApi();
const loginOps = {
    apiPassword: true,
    includeAccountIdGuid: true
};

authApi.login(loginOps, function (err, loginInfo, response) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    if (loginInfo) {

        // loginInfo returns 'exports {}' so the variables below cannot be set.

        const loginAccounts = loginInfo.loginAccounts;
        const loginAccount = loginAccounts[0];
        const baseUrl = loginAccount.baseUrl;
        const accountDomain = baseUrl.split('/v2');
        const accountId = loginAccount.accountId;

        apiClient.setBasePath(accountDomain[0]);
        docusign.Configuration.default.setDefaultApiClient(apiClient);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`www.docusign.net` endpoint will only work if your PROD account is in NA1, if your PROD Account is in NA2, then you need to use `na2.docusign.net` and if it is in NA3 then `na3.docusign.net`. This is the main reason you should use `/oauth/userinfo` call with OAUTH2 Access Token to know your base URL, and then call all APIs with this baseURL. You can find more details at https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/userinfo.html